# Math operations bewteen columns with AWK

Tags: awk, multiple-columns

I have a data file like this:

```
a 1 1  m n l o p
b 2 2
c 3 3
```

I want to do math calculations by using columns m n l o and p in order to get the following output:

```
a 1*m+1*n+p+o-l
b 2*m+2*n+p+o-l
c 3*m+3*n+p+o-l
```

Do you have any idea how to do this in AWK?

Comment: your m,n,o,p are having integer values in them?

Comment: Yes, m n l o p are numbers actually.

Comment: cool, then. Let me know if my solutions helps you. Enjoy learning !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly but it seems to work:

```
awk 'NR==1{ m = $4; n = $5; l= $6; o = $7; p= $8}{ print $1,$2*m+$3*n+p+o-l }' yourfile
```

The first part is catching your m n l o p and storing them in variables and the second parts executes your desired math operation for every line.

Comment: Cool Cool. Have fun with it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1{split($0,a)}{print $1,$2*a[4]+$3*a[5]+a[8]+a[7]-a[6]}' file
```